# Exception while using apache lucene for stop words removal

Tags: lucene, stop-words

I am using following code for stop words removal from input text. I am getting following exception when  `tokenStream.incrementToken()` runs.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: TokenStream contract violation: reset()/close() call missing, reset() called multiple times, or subclass does not call super.reset(). Please see Javadocs of TokenStream class for more information about the correct consuming workflow.
```

Code :

```
public static String removeStopWords(String textFile) throws Exception {
        CharArraySet stopWords = EnglishAnalyzer.getDefaultStopSet();
        TokenStream tokenStream = new StandardTokenizer();
        tokenStream = new StopFilter(tokenStream, stopWords);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        CharTermAttribute charTermAttribute = tokenStream.addAttribute(CharTermAttribute.class);
        tokenStream.reset();
        while (tokenStream.incrementToken()) {
            String term = charTermAttribute.toString();
            sb.append(term + " ");
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instantiate your TokenStream as below -

```
TokenStream tokenStream = new StandardAnalyzer().tokenStream("field",new StringReader(textFile));
```

Comment: "field" is the name of the field (IndexableField) the created TokenStream is used for. If your tokenStream is not specific to a field, you can pass null instead. Also, since your input is a String, you can use - `tokenStream(null, textFile);`